# Retriving value from href using python selenium

Tags: python, selenium, bots, ranking, browser-automation

```
<a class="yt-simple-endpoint style-scope yt-formatted-string" spellcheck="false" href="/channel/UC8butISFwT-Wl7EV0hUK0BQ" dir="auto">freeCodeCamp.org</a>
```

I am new to selenium and trying to make a youtube rank check bot!
I am trying to get the href value from here so that I can compare it with the channel name and print out the proper ranking number but the outputs that I am getting are not correct.
The outputs I am getting are 2,5 where I should be getting 6,7.

Can anyone please tell me where/what am I doing wrong? And what can be done to solve this problem? Advance thanks

Screenshot attached below to see the rankings
[image]

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
channel_name = 'freeCodeCamp.org' #channel name
driver = webdriver.Chrome(r"C:\\Users\\user\\PycharmProjects\\YoutubeRankCheckBot\\Drivers\\chromedriver.exe")
driver.get("http://youtube.com")
driver.maximize_window()

search_bar = driver.find_element_by_id("search")
search_bar.send_keys("React JS") #Inserting text input in a automation way
search_button = driver.find_element_by_id("search-icon-legacy")
search_button.click()

time.sleep(5)


video_list = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//a[contains(@href,"/channel/UC8butISFwT-Wl7EV0hUK0BQ")]')
print(video_list)

for index, channel in enumerate(video_list):
    if channel.text  == channel_name:
        print(index)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 video_list = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//a[@class="style-scope ytd-video-renderer"]')
video_url = [video_list.get_attribute('href').replace('https://www.youtube.com', '') for video_list in video_list]
print(video_url)

for index, channel in enumerate(video_url):
    if channel == channel_id:
        print(index)
```

Here `channel_id`  is nothing but `/channel/UC8butISFwT-Wl7EV0hUK0BQ` for the channel name `freeCodeCamp.org`.

1. First line gives all the element of `a` tag
2. From a list of step 1, find the `href` element. It will give you the complete URL for e.g. `https://www.youtube.com/channel/UC8butISFwT-Wl7EV0hUK0BQ`. so replacing `https://www.youtube.com` and extracting into `video_url`
3. Enumerate with `video_url` and print the `index`

Comment: ['/user/TechGuyWeb', '/user/programmingwithmosh', '/user/programmingwithmosh', '/channel/UC8butISFwT-Wl7EV0hUK0BQ',......]

The video_url list is showing programming with mosh twice at index = 1 & 2 but mosh came only once in the ranking at index = 1.

Then came the desired url twice in index number 3 & 4 but in the ranking, it came in the 7th & 8th place (index = 6 & 7)

Comment: `user/programmingwithmosh` has two entries - 1. React JS - React Tutorial for Beginners and 2. What is React (React JS) & Why it is so popular?

Comment: Note: suggestion from youtube may differ from one person to other. As I am receiving twice `user/programmingwithmosh`

Comment: Yeah, I know that suggestions differ from user to user.
But, that's the correct result u're getting according to the suggestion pattern by executing the code, shouldn't I get the outputs according to my suggestion pattern when I execute the code? :(

Comment: Wait, It's working but it's not counting the playlists. That's okay I guess.
Thank u so much. I can't express my gratitude in words. 
I've been dealing with it for almost the last 2.5 days. Thank you @Vijay Dodamani brother

Answer (score 0):

You are using wrong locators.
Try this:

```
video_list = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@id='channel-info']//a[@class='yt-simple-endpoint style-scope yt-formatted-string']")
```

**UPD**
After your explanation I understand a bit more.
You can find those specific elements with this:

```
//div[@id='channel-info']//a[@class='yt-simple-endpoint style-scope yt-formatted-string' and (contains(@href,"/channel/UC8butISFwT-Wl7EV0hUK0BQ"))]
```

This will give you 2 elements since there are 2 videos from that channel in that search results

Comment: I tried it before actually and now, I ran the code again with ur solution but got 3,5!
This time the ranking changed a bit so I should've gotten 6 & 8. :(

Comment: I don't really understand what are you trying to do? The question title in not what I see in the question body... Can you clarify?

Comment: OKay, I now see what I did to confuse u! My apologies.
What I am trying to do is make a list of all the href values and match it with my specific href value ("/channel/UC8butISFwT-Wl7EV0hUK0BQ")
The ones that will match, those matched one's indexes will be my answer.

But so far, no luck.  I am dealing with it for almost 24 hours straight and posted it here after not fining any solution by my own. Any help will be very appreciatable.

Comment: Well, now I understand a bit more. Please see if this is what you are looking for?

Comment: I copied and pasted ur snippet into the driver.find_elements_by_xpath("") within inverted commas but there was a bit of syntax error so I modified a bit but still no luck. 
Now it's showing 0 & 1! :( 

Modification: 

video_list = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@id='channel-info']//a[@class='yt-simple-endpoint style-scope yt-formatted-string' and (contains(@href,'/channel/UC8butISFwT-Wl7EV0hUK0BQ'))]")

Comment: Apologies for the late reply, I wasn't online.
Unfortunately, No..it's still not working! :(